# Embedding iframe at the top/bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that injects an iframe at the top/bottom of the page in a fixed position. The problem is that in most of the websites once I inject the iframe it comes on top of the header/footer. What I want to achieve is to inject it and shift the header/footer so that it doesn't come on top of it.

**iframe.html**

```
<body>
        <div>This is a div</div>
</body>
```

**iframe.css**

```
.div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000000000;
    background-color: red;
    height: 30px !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**content.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;
    if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
        var iframe = $("<iframe></iframe>");
        iframe_src = chrome.runtime.getURL('iframe.html');
        iframe.attr("src",iframe_src);
        $("html").append(iframe);
    }
});
```

**content.css**

```
/****Top****/
iframe{
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000000000;
    width: 100%;
}

/****Bottom*****/
iframe{
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000000000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you give the `<body>` a margin or padding and push the `<iframe>` into that?

Comment: @Twisty not working. I think something has to be done to each page before injecting the iframe, but I don't seem to find out what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/p54Lmfbg/8/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("body").css({
    marginTop: "30px"
  });

  $("<iframe>", {
    class: "top-frame"
  }).css({
    border: "1px solid #ccc",
    height: "28px",
    position: "fixed",
    top: "0",
    left: "0",
    zIndex: "1000000000",
    width: "100%"
  }).appendTo("body");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("iframe.top-frame").contents().find("body").html("<div>This is a div in a Frame.</div>");
  }, 100);
});
```

Your code will be different since you are adjusting the Source of the Frame. It might be best to still use `.ready()` or `setTimeout` to allow the frame to load or become ready.

Comment: I appreciate your solution. But this will not always work, especially if the header is fixed (As the case in Stackoverflow). I need a near general solution (if exists) that will work in most cases.